# Find the value of the variable $p$

Tags: probability

I'm looking to find the value of the variable "p" using different ways if possible.

> $$\sum_{x=1}^{4012}{4012\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{4012-x}=1.$$

Comment: Side note: Without showing at least a minimal amount of effort, you are more likely to get down-votes than answers.

Comment: If I am not mistaken x goes from 0 to 4012.

Comment: @zoli it doesn't have to, see my answer for details

Comment: Also, Hamza:  welcome to MSE, you should know that generally you want to post your own thoughts/work or at least some more context or you risk your topic being down-voted or outright closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $p=0$ is a possibility, however if not then since you're missing the $x=0$ term then that means $p^0(1-p)^{4012}=0$ because your sum is equal to

$$1^{4012}-{4012\choose 0}\cdot p^0(1-p)^{4012}$$

by the binomial theorem, i.e. $p=1$ is the only other option.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Binomial Distribution for $n=4012$ and $p$ unknown.

It's probability function is $f(x) = \binom{4012}{x} p^x (1- p)^{4012-x}$
This is the probability that you succeed in exactly $x$ out of 4012 trials.

It's cumulative probability function is $F(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{x} f(k)$
This is the probability that you succeed in at most $x$ trials.

For the binomial distribution, $F(x) = 1$ only at $x=\infty$ outside of a degenerate case where $f(x) = 1$ for some $x$.

This is that degenerate case. For $f(x) = 1$, it was shown by [Adam Hughes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1168276/187120) that the only possible $p$ is $1$.

The reasoning behind this is that if you want to be 100% sure that you succeed in 4012 trials, you need to be 100% sure that you succeed in any number of trials.
To be 100% sure that you succeed in any number of trials, you need to be 100% sure that you succeed in one trial.
To be 100% sure that you succeed in one trial, you need a 100% chance at success.